# PHP find double values in array and enumerate them

Tags: php, arrays, double, enumeration

Hi I'm looking forward do find an easy solution to find and enumerate double values.

```
array("Papples", "Gelato", "Gelato", "Banana", "Papples","Papples")
```

to:

```
array("Papples", "Gelato", "Gelato2", "Banana", "Papples2","Papples3")
```

I could do it with a loop with if and write to second array procedure but isn't there a better solution for it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
<?php
$arr = array("Papples", "Gelato", "Gelato", "Banana", "Papples","Papples");

$countarray = array_count_values($arr);

$resultarray = array();
foreach ($countarray as $key=>$value) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $value; $i++) {
     $resultarray[]=$key.$i;
    }
}

print_r($resultarray);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go with the loop and `if`, it's not difficult and will be pretty fast.

```
$delicatessen = [
    "Papples", "Gelato", "Gelato", "Banana", "Papples","Papples"
];

foreach ($delicatessen as $e) {
    if (@$counter[$e]++) $e .= $counter[$e];
    $new[] = $e;
}
```

Basically what this does is to always  add the element to the new array,
clearly, but modifying it or not.  The condition is the `$counter` array
which will store the amount of times an item appears. All is created "on
the fly", PHP allows that.

When we retrieve `$counter[$e]` this element  does not exist yet, so the
returned value makes the condition fail.  However there is a side effect
that after  the undef is returned,  it will be increased  (with `++`) so
now `$counter[$e]` will be `1`.

If on  a future iteration this  is accessed again the  returned value of
`1` will make the condition pass, with the side affect that at the point
the `if` statement  is executed `$counter[$e]` will already  be `2`. The
statement concatenated this number to the end of the element.

This way,  in the first  time nothing is  concatenated but there  is the
side  effect. On  next  iterations  the number  is  concatenated to  the
element.

The `@`  operator is  used here  to suppress  PHP notices.  Since you're
dealing with  undefined elements on  first pass, you would  get notices.
Script wouldn't  break though. Of  course this  operator should  be used
with caution,  but in this case  it just really helps  simplifying code,
making it less strict.

Comment: Can you please explain that `if` condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array("Papples", "Gelato", "Gelato", "Banana", "Papples","Papples");
    $arr_count = array_count_values($arr);
    $new_arr = array();
    foreach($arr_count as $key=>$val){
        if($val > 1){
            $k = 1;
            for($i=0; $i<$val; $i++){
                if($i==0){
                  $new_arr[] = $key;  
                }else{
                    $new_arr[] = $key.++$k;  
                }
            }
        }else{
            $new_arr[] = $key;
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($new_arr);
```

Test script: https://3v4l.org/iGf1s